# Bootable Ubuntu partition on Mac. Help!

Tags: partitioning

```
hdiutil convert -format Rdxx -o /Volumes/"NO NAME.img" /Macintosh HD/Users/nickzieno/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.img /Macintosh HD/Users/nickzieno/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
```

I Enter all this and this is the outcome of it.

```
hdiutil: convert: only a single input file can be specified
Usage:  hdiutil convert -format <format> -o <outfile> [options] <image>
    hdiutil convert -help
```

Been staring at this for days trying to figure it out but have come up with nothing

sudo dd if=/Macintosh HD/Users/nickzieno/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs-1m

IM now getting this after I enter all of that

dd: unknown operand HD/Users/nickzieno/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the space character between "`if=/Macintosh`" and "`HD/Users/nickzieno/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.img` tells your shell that it has TWO parameters. Either quote the whole thing (`sudo dd "if=/Macintosh HD/Users/nickzieno/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.img"  of=/dev/rdiskN  bs-1m`) or use backslash to escape the space (`...Macintosh\ HD/...`).

Also I think that the `N` in `/dev/rdiskN` should be replaced by a digit, and `bs-1m` should be `bs=1m`